# Open in a new tab the bulk actions and do not let select field if it has already been selected prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, checkboxlist, bulk

I'm working on prsetashop 1.6 right now.

I have a module that displays a data listing and I'm using bulk actions to select those rows that I want to open in a new jane form, it's already working but open in the same window and I wanted to in a new tab.

Another part is that I wanted to not show up on the lines that I have previously selected.

I'll show you the code I have.
I really need help.

```
(...)   
    $helper = new HelperList();
    $helper->module = $this;
    $helper->shopLinkType = '';
    $helper->simple_header = false;
    $helper->identifier = 'id_contabilidade_faturacao';
    $helper->actions = array('edit', 'envio');
    $helper->show_toolbar = true;
    $count = '<span class="badge">'.count($content).'</span>';
    $helper->title = $this->l('List Invoices Download').': '.$count;
    $helper->table = $table;
    $helper->bulk_actions = array(
        'enviar_email' => array(
            'text' => $this->l('Selecionar para envio email'),
            'icon' => 'icon-send',
            'confirm' => $this->l('Tem a certeza que selecionou corretamente?')
        )
    );
    $helper->{$helper->table.'_pagination'} = 50;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
    $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
     //var_dump($this->displayAddLink($token = null, $id, $name = null), $this->displayEnvioLink($token = null, $id, $name = null));exit;
    $this->_html .= $helper->generateList($content, $this->fields_list);
}
```

Comment: Hi did you find out how to open up the bulk actions in a new tab?